# Package installed and not installed at the same time

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

Sometime ago I tried to install Steam on my CentOS 5 server and tried almost everything I found on Internet and it seems that I have been able to leave libstdc++ installed and not installed at the same time.

CPanel is failing to update because it doesn't find the correct version installed but yum is unable to install it because it's already installed.

¿How can I fix this situation and reach a consistent state?

```
# yum install libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * contrib: mirror.wiredtree.com
addons                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
centosplus                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00
contrib                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
wiredtree                                                |  951 B     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package matching libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do

# yum remove libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * contrib: mirror.wiredtree.com
addons                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
centosplus                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00
contrib                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
wiredtree                                                |  951 B     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Package(s) libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal


# yum reinstall libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * contrib: mirror.wiredtree.com
addons                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
centosplus                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00
contrib                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
wiredtree                                                |  951 B     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
No Match for argument: libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5
Package(s) libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5 available, but not installed.
Nothing to do

# yum --showduplicates list libstdc++ | expand
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * contrib: mirror.wiredtree.com
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Installed Packages
libstdc++.i386                      4.3.2-7                            installed
Available Packages
libstdc++.i386                      4.1.2-55.el5                       base
```

Comment: I would flush and re-install. Don't waste your time trying to salvage it. Take you 20 minutes to re-install the base OS.

Comment: No that easy when it is a web server online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Anthony Geoghegan pointing me in the right direction, I was able to find a working solution

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps libstdc++
```

That will remove the pacakge from the db without touching the files, then simple `yum install` will work.

Comment: Glad to have helped. I've had to use `--nodeps` a couple of times when rpm was confused but I wasn't aware of the `--justdb` option.

Comment: I had to do the same for libstdc++-devel as well. Thanks for bringing your solution back here.

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest, I’d first try removing the package using the `rpm` command:

```
rpm -e libstdc++
```

However, I suspect that `rpm`’s internal database is corrupted and the above
command won’t work so I’d then try rebuilding its database using:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: --rebuild did nothing and removing the package was not an option due to all of the dependencies but searching around the rpm command I was able to solve it so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen on x86_64 and multilib package. `yum remove libstdc++` tries to remove 64bits version, but that is not installed. So in such situation you should address the package with arch. I.e:

```
yum remove libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.i386
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation on my host.

```
# yum --showduplicates list coreutils-libs
```

returned two versions of the same package apparently installed at the same time.

```
Installed Packages
coreutils-libs.x86_64                  8.4-37.el6_7.3                 @updates
coreutils-libs.x86_64                  8.4-43.el6                     installed
Available Packages
coreutils-libs.x86_64                  8.4-43.el6                     base
```

When I tried

```
# yum remove coreutils-libs
```

it failed, because it would have to remove other dependencies, including *yum* itself.

However, after several trials and errors I was able to fix that.  The key is to use full name of the package, i.e. including the version and release suffix.

The main point is, that removing one of the packages would require physical removal but removing the other of the two will just remove the rpm DB record and thus bring the database into a consistent state.

In my case I could see I also had **coreutils-8.4-37.el6_7.3** package installed, so the release -37.el6_7.3 was probably the right one (i.e. to be preserved).

When I told *yum* to remove the other one

```
# yum remove coreutils-libs-8.4-43.el6
```

everything ran without any error and RPM DB became consistent again.